# Sum of a column of a data frame in R

Tags: r

R newbie here. I have a csv sheet which i have sorted my data according to gender (Child's sex). I want to add/sum the column up to a certain point only, in this case I want to sum the Child's age column from column 301 to 311 then store the value, and then 312 to 336. how do i do this in r. Thanks

[image]

Comment: read about `aggregate`

Answer (score 0):

You could `library(data.table)`:

```
data <- as.data.table( read.csv(file.choose(), header = T) )
data[,.(age_sum = sum(age)), by=list(child_sex) ]
```